# refresh component after request ajax

Tags: angular

I tried the solutions to other questions, but they did not work

After inserting into my database I would like to update my component (The user needs to continue on the same component).

I tried to navigate to the component itself:

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin/product']);
```

I tried to go to another and go back to him:

```
this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
this.router.navigate(['/admin/product']);
```

None worked! I want the component to be reloaded to stay current with the database information. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: After inserting, the DB send back the created object ? you should show your component code

Comment: That's not enough information. Where do you have your above code? Where is it being called from? What is not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question not being entirely clear, but from what I understand:

"***How to stay current with database information***"

suggests to me that you do not need to reload your entire component, just make an api call to get the updated data. So after you had added data to your db, you just call to get the updated data. So dummy example would be:

```ts
addItem() {
  this.myService.addItem()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.getAllItems(); // do the call here to update!
    });
}
```

Comment: Did t´his answer help you? :)